# Update linux kernel to > 3.15-rc5 and still use CentOS 6.5

Tags: linux, centos, virtual-server

I am running CentOS 6.5 on top of Linux kernel 2.6.32-358.6.1.el6.x86_64

I got a warning from my vserver hoster that I need to upgrade to a Linux kernel > 3.15-rc5 because there is a security breach that would allow my server to be taken over.

I did a yumupgrade, but it wouldn't upgrade the kernel to a higher version than 2.6.32-358.6.1.el6.x86_64.

Currently I am confused about how to go on.

Could anybody tell me what is going on and how he would act in my position?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That kernel is a development kernel and will likely require you compile from source to install it. Upgrading from kernel 2.6 to 3.1n will likely break a bunch of packages also. The upgrade path for 3.1n in CentOS would be to upgrade to CentOS7 and then compile that kernel yourself.

CentOS backports security fixes and I certainly haven't heard anything about any security bug, and we manage like 150 centos servers. I would ask your host to specify what the security bug is and which patch applied in the 3.15-rc5 kernel fixes it. Who's the host?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using CentOS 6.5 and have no problem using the ElRepo Long term kernel (currently 3.10.x).

See http://elrepo.org/tiki/kernel-lt

Upgrading was just a case of

```
yum --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel install kernel-lt
```

and rebooting.